# django vue js & Highcharts asynchronously fetching data from JSON

Tags: javascript, python, django, vue.js, highcharts

I'm  currently Using django,highcharts, and JQuery to build a simple data visualization web app. I just moved from JQuery to Vue Js and I'm confused on how vue js to fetch JSON data from certain url. Here is my code:

Template

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Django Highcharts Example</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="container" data-url="{% url 'async_chart_data' %}"></div>
  <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.src.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $.ajax({
      url: $("#container").attr("data-url"),
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function (data) {
        Highcharts.chart("container", data);
      }
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Views.py

```
 def chart_view(request):
     return render(request,'chart.html')

 def chart_data(request):
     dataset = Passenger.objects.values('embarked')\
     .exclude(embarked='')\
     .annotate(total=Count('embarked'))\
     .order_by('embarked')

     port_name = dict()
     for choices_tuple in Passenger.PORT_CHOICES:
         port_name[choices_tuple[0]] = choices_tuple[1]

     #Hicharts visualization config
     pie_chart = {
        'chart' : {'type':'pie'},
        'title' : {'text' : 'PELABUHAN'},
        'series': [{
           'name' : 'Tempat Berangkat',
           'data' : list(map(lambda row: {'name' : port_name[row['embarked']],
            'y' : row['total']},dataset))
       }]
     }

     return JsonResponse(pie_chart)
```

Models.py

```
 from django.db import models

 class Passenger(models.Model):
       MALE = 'M'
       FEMALE = 'F'

      SEX_CHOICES = (
         (MALE, 'male'),
         (FEMALE, 'female')
       )

       CHERBOURG = 'C'
       QUEENSTOWN = 'Q'
       SOUTHAMPTON = 'S'

        PORT_CHOICES = (
           (CHERBOURG, 'Cherbourg'),
           (QUEENSTOWN, 'Queenstown'),
           (SOUTHAMPTON, 'Southampton'),
       )

      name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
      sex = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=SEX_CHOICES)
      survived = models.BooleanField()
      age = models.FloatField(null=True)
      ticket_class = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
      embarked = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=PORT_CHOICES)

      def __str__(self):
         return self.name
```

I wanna change the JQuery usage to fetch the JSON data to Vue JS. How I can do it ?

EDIT: i'M already done with this issue. I'm run to another issue on [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51016202/issue-in-vuejs-axios-and-highcharts-integration-slow-performance)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Case is closed. I'm able to achieve it by playing with vue js life cycle hooks. However it still slow enough to load the page. need(4 to 7 seconds) but it works. Here is my template.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Using Vue Axios</title>
 <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>
 <script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.src.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="app">[[dataTitanic]]</div>
 <h1>The Chart Is Shown Below : </h1>
 <div id="container"></div>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  var url = "{% url 'async_chart_data' %}";
  var app = new Vue({
   delimiters : ['[[',']]'],
   el : '#app',
   data(){
    return {
     dataTitanic : null,
    }
   },
   mounted(){
    axios
      .get(url)
      .then(response => (this.dataTitanic = response['data']))
   },
   beforeUpdate(){
    Highcharts.chart('container',this.dataTitanic)
   }
  })
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```